# Trying to get the latest entry of a Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

So I am trying to make a webpage that on the first page puts the three latest recipes that have been added. I know how to loop through all of the recipes, but I am having trouble finding out how to call only the latest, second-latest, and third-latest recipes.
Here is my models:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    """A recipe the user is learning about."""

    text = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.text
```

Here is my view

```
@login_required
def recipes(request):
    """Show all recipes"""
    recipes = Recipe.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by("-date_added")
    context = {"recipes": recipes}
    return render(request, "recipe_book/recipes.xhtml", context)


@login_required
def recipe(request, recipe_id):
    """Show a single recipe and all its entries"""
    recipe = Recipe.objects.get(id=recipe_id)
    # Make sure the recipe belongs to the current user
    if recipe.owner != request.user:
        raise Http404
    # Show all entries for this recipe
    ingredients = recipe.ingredient_set.order_by("-time_added")
    context = {
        "recipe": recipe,
        "ingredients": ingredients,
    }
    return render(request, "recipe_book/recipe.xhtml", context)
```

My url

```
app_name = "recipe_book"
...
# Page that shows all recipes
    path("recipes/", views.recipes, name="recipes"),
    # Detail page for a single recipe
    path("recipes/<int:recipe_id>/", views.recipe, name="recipe"),
```

My index I am trying to make buttons that link to those 3 latest recipes that have been added.

I tried making a new view and url pattern but it did not work, or I didn't know how to code them.

Answer (score 1):

You limit the queryset through slicing:

```
@login_required
def recipes(request):
    """Show all recipes"""
    # 🖟 slice [:3]
    recipes = Recipe.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by('-date_added')[
        :3
    ]
    context = {'recipes': recipes}
    return render(request, 'recipe_book/recipes.xhtml', context)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying! Can you please help me with the view, that's where I am having trouble, because I'm not very fluent with html. Also I am using bootstrap.

Comment: It is exactly the same template as before, the loop will just enumerate over the first three items.

Comment: Thanks @WillemVanOnsem it's working now!

Answer (score 1):

We can limit the records by using list indices as python

```
latest_records = Recipe.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by('-date_added')[:3]
```

These will fetch top 3 latest records

If you want fetch nth lastest record, you can use `offset` clause with limit

```
latest_third_record = Recipe.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by('-date_added')[2:3]
```

This will return the 3rd latest record of that user.

More information: [Django ORM equivalent of LIMIT in sql](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets)

Comment: It will not raise an `IndexError`, since you here *slice*, you don't index... In case no record exists, it will return an empty queryset.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying!Can you please help me with the view, that's where I am having trouble, because I'm not very fluent with html. I am trying to make buttons that when you click, send you to the recipe page. Also I am using bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you so much @WillemVanOnsem. I have edited my answer.